# Swift/iOS "impossible" concurrency bug

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, memory-model

I've encountered a bug in some iOS code, which appears to be impossible.

The following code may not quite work for you, as we've modified the version of [Safe](https://github.com/tidwall/Safe) that it uses.  The bug should still be impossible, no matter how badly we broke Safe.  Consider:

```
private func tests() {
    let (cin, cout) = Chan<Int>().io()

    let MSGS = 1000
    let SENDERS = 100

    let wgs = WaitGroup()
    wgs.add(1)

    let wgf = WaitGroup()

    var sending = [Bool](repeating: false, count: SENDERS)

    wgf.add(1)
    dispatch {
        wgs.wait()
        var sum = 0
        for _ in 1...(SENDERS*MSGS) {
            let sender = cin.startReceive().msg!
            sum += 1
            if !sending[sender] {
                print("Error! \(sender)")
            }
            cin.endReceive()
        }
        print("sum \(sum) =? \(sum == (SENDERS*MSGS))")
        wgf.done()
    }

    for sender in 0..<SENDERS {
        let co = cout

        wgf.add(1)
        dispatch {
            wgs.wait()
            Thread.current.name = "Sender \(sender)"
            print("sender \(sender) start")
            for _ in 1...MSGS {
                sending[sender] = true
                print("sender \(sender) \(sending[sender])")
                co.send(sender)
                sending[sender] = false
            }
            print("sender \(sender) end")
            wgf.done()
        }
    }

    dispatch {
        sm.run()
    }

    wgs.done()
    wgf.wait()
}
```

To help you read the code, and understand the context, know the following:

1. WaitGroup is equivalent to Java's CountDownLatch - all calls to `.wait()` block until enough `.done()` calls have been made.
2. The channel (`Chan`) is a method of communicating between threads.  Used here, `.send(X)` blocks, `.startReceive()` eventually gets `X`, but `.send(X)` continues to block until `.endReceive()` is subsequently called.  (This is called "extended rendezvous" in CSP jargon.  (CSP = Communicating Sequential Processes))
3. `dispatch` spawns a new thread that runs the attached block.

Now, these details are (or should be) largely immaterial, because the most disconcerting symptom is as follows: once in a while, `sending[sender]` will be false on the `co.send(sender)` line, which is between `sending[sender] = true` and `sending[sender] = false`, apparently even as viewed from the sending thread.

More detail: when this code is run, the following events occur for me:

1. I create an array of 100 `Bool`s, to track which threads are currently sending.
2. I spin up a receiving thread and 100 sending threads.
3. The sending threads start sending their 1000 messages.

   1. For each message, a given sender will set its tracking `Bool` in `sending` to true, send its id, and set its tracking `Bool` to false.  As the sender threads are created in a loop with its id set from the loop's index, there should only be one thread per id, and thus only one thread writing a given index of `sending`.  (The receiver only reads.)
4. The receiver receives messages as they are sent.

   1. The sender is blocked while the receiver processes its message.
   2. As part of "processing", I check `sending` to make sure the sender is still marked as being in the middle of sending.  The purpose was to verify that extended rendezvous was functioning correctly: if `.startReceive()` erroneously unblocked the sender, the sender would subsequently set its tracker to false, which (depending on race conditions) might get picked up by the receiver.
5. In my runs, the receiver DOES detect a handful of errors per run.
6. Now, this alone is slightly perplexing, but might merely mean the library code is broken.
7. ...Except, when I put a breakpoint on the `print("Error! \(sender)")` line, and check the corresponding sender thread, the debugger tells me it IS still in the middle of the `.send(X)` call, BUT `sending[sender]` is false.  This should be impossible.

To reiterate the bottom line, the debugger is telling me that occasionally on the `send` of

```
sending[sender] = true
print("sender \(sender) \(sending[sender])")
co.send(sender)     ////// HERE
sending[sender] = false
```

that `sending[sender]` is false.  Now, I JUST discovered that the `print` just before the `send` DOES sometime report false, though not always.  Here's a screenshot: (note that there is no "Error!" message, because I put a breakpoint ON that message.  Also note I scaled down to 10 senders, for log brevity.)

[image: Bug]

Given this confirmation that the thread itself sees a weird state, my leading explanation is as follows:

Because arrays in Swift are values rather than objects, and copied when modified (I think), there is apparently a race condition that can happen when two threads set (different) values of an array.  If the timing is right, only one of the modifications survives.

Is that a reasonable explanation for the observed behavior?